# Commutation of filtered colimits and finite limits in $\mathbb{CGWH}$

Tags: ct.category-theory, gn.general-topology

Do filtered colimits and finite limits (in particular pullbacks) commute in the category of compactly generated weak Hausdorff spaces?

Answer (score 6):

No. See example 6.6 in Strickland's note, [The category of CGWH spaces](https://neil-strickland.staff.shef.ac.uk/courses/homotopy/cgwh.pdf).